# How to change background color of custom view placed in actionbar?

Tags: android

What I did was

```
View v=getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.action_bar, null);
        v.setBackgroundResource(R.color.Primary_color);
actionbar.setCustomView(v);
```

Everything worked fine but how do i again change the color of custom view below statement is not working why.

```
getActionBar().getCustomView().setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#3f51b5"));
```

Comment: Hi Have you tried changing background color of layout file which you are inflating ?

Comment: No why should I want to do that? I thought getCustomView is enough

Comment: I tried that its not working

Comment: are you getting grayish color instead desired color ?

Comment: No Shrenik I finally found the solution instead of setting customview i just set the layout background to be transparent, it solved the issue thank u for helping

Comment: oh! that's great news @Prince Jayakumar